# global python lists in external module replacing each other's values

Tags: python

I have a file config.py with two values

```
score_param = [-3.24097637368454,0,0,0,0,0]
p = [-3.24097637368454, 
 0.587524975207248, 
 0.630901213219356, 
 0.647563874895472, 
 -0.547490987136909, 
 -0.851756955173558, 
 -0.840787900229345, 
 -0.230491995673875]
```

When I import this module to another one called config_beta.py and call in a loop config.score_param, it takes values of config.p

EDIT (importing config.py in config_beta.py):

congif_beta.py

```
from config import *
```

importing config_beta.py

```
import importlib
import sys
#import parameters

env = sys.argv[1]

config = importlib.import_module('config_'+env)
param = config.score_param

for i in range(1,100):
    print param
```

Offcourse, the above code was in a class with multiple objects being initited. I can't share the entire code for confidentiality.

To combat this I created a new list for score_param as

```
param = [config.p[0],0,0,0,0,0]
```

Is this because the first value of p and score_param the same and both are global in the config.py
It could also be some other issue but I would like to know if I am getting wrong some basic practice of declaring global variables in external modules.

Comment: Can you show the code for import and 'call'?

Comment: Can not reproduce. Are you 100% sure it is this module you are importing, and not e.g. an older version of it?

Comment: Should not happen. Post code that imports.

Comment: Something else is going on, post your import code and use case.

Comment: added the exact process of importing

Comment: @tobias_k config_beta.py

Comment: Wait... just to get this straight. You are importing `config.py` into `config_beta.py`, and then import `config_beta`, and there the fields are mixed up... show us how you import `config` into `config_beta` then!

Comment: @tobias_k done. there is no modifcation of values in config_beta. config_beta is just to be able to overload some values in config

Comment: I'm sure you already checked this, but I guess `config_beta` is not overloading the value of `score_param` by any chance, is it?

Comment: @tobias_k nope no overloading in config_beta.py. trust me it was bizzare for me to see what happened. also, when i practice this from another module without objects and classes with iterations, it works

Comment: Your code works perfectly and as expected for me. Can you please post your output and describe in detail what exactly is supposed to happen?